# Outlook ICS file, show Link as Hyperlink

Tags: outlook, icalendar

I have an outlook ICS file. When I open it in Outlook and then double click on any event, sometimes the link show up as a Hyperlink and sometimes it dooes not.

Can anybody please tell me what change I need to make in the format such that the link shows up as Hyperlink in the mail?

The file is here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B37FvLpUIq9sTUt4V3FfemJ4Qkk/edit?usp=sharing

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides the DESCRIPTION part, you also need to use X-ALT-DESC part with the FMTTYPE attribute equal to text/html) - you can then include HTML with an explicitly specified link.

An example is

```
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//E
    N">\n<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n<META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="MS Exchange Server ve
    rsion 08.01.0240.003">\n<TITLE></TITLE>\n</HEAD>\n<BODY>\n<!-- Converted f
    rom text/rtf format -->\n\n<P DIR=LTR><SPAN LANG="en-us"></SPAN></P>\n\n</
    BODY>\n</HTML>
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer seems to be perfect. Can you please provide example of 1 entry with the changes you specified?